# Make Python seaborn heatmap bigger

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I use a heat map in Python to show the correlation between all parameters I have. The number of parameters however are that large that the heat map becomes to small to show the data.

[Heat Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLgh4.png)

The heat map is created using seaborn:

```
seaborn.heatmap(df.corr())
```

I tried to make it bigger using:

```
plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
seaborn.heatmap(df.corr())
```

but this didn't work since the image just remained its current size.

Does someone know another way of doing this? Or maybe another way to clearly plot the correlations between all parameters?

Regards, Ganesh

Comment: Did you use plt.show() to display? If you are doing this in a Jupyter notebook, it may just be displaying your old command, without processing `plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))`. You might also use `plt.savefig('img.png', dpi = 600)` to increase the resolution.

Comment: To save the image is a very smart idea. The only problem with that is because of its small size, some labels are not showed. I want to make the image bigger so that all labels can be displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the figure first (similar to how you tried) using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
```

Then, pass in `ax` as an argument to `seaborn.heatmap`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
seaborn.heatmap(df.corr(), ax=ax)
plt.show()
```